# Grouping of summaries during hyperparameter search in tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorboard, hyperparameters

I would like to perform a hyperparameter search. On each combination of parameters, I am creating appropriate graph and run training on it. Inside graph I have summaries like likelihood plots.

How to organize tensorboard reporting in order to see everything in one page?

I can have different logdir names, what are else options?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have experiment1 and experiment2, each of them corresponds to a different hyperparam setting, the best way will be to save the summaries is in the following structure:

```
<base_path>/experiment1/ 
<base_path>/experiment2/
```

Now, when invoking tensorboard, to see comparison of the experiments according to the summaries defined, load tensorboard with `logsdir=<base_path>`

Note that in order to see a comparison of the different settings you must give each summary a name that is not dependent on a specific setting. For example, `tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss)` is good but `tf.summary.scalar("loss_%s"%(experiment_id), loss)` will result in different summary plot for each different setting.